# How to remove the hover background color from a specific anchor tag with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to remove the hover that's applied to all anchor tags in bootstrap 3.0.3. Here is my basic structure

```
<ul class="nav affix-top">
  <li class="menu-text"><a href="#">hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried using !important in my css but so far no luck

```
.menu-text a:hover {
  background-color: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your CSS-expression is not specific enough an overruled by another expression, have you checked with Firebug?

Try something like this

```
ul.nav li.menu-text a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

PS: `background-color: none` is not a valid option. Use `transparent` instead.